# QTP & IE9: Record no scripts in SAP Web, but Object Spy could recognize element

Tags: automation, automated-tests, record, qtp, noscript

I am facing a weird problem using QTP (Version 11), that when I did some actions in the web, no scripts will be recorded, while I could be able to recognize elements in the web.
i.e.
when I click a button "set up", no script will be recorded in the "Expert View", while when I use "Object Spy" to recognize that button, I could be able to get it.
[image: This is the Object Spy for this button]

[image: This is the expert view after click the button]

It is so weird because QTP is able to record on other web pages, could it result from the settings of my target server?

The patches I installed are QTP_00699,QTPWEB_00101, QTPWEB_00078, and I am using IE9, with QTP version 11.

--
Updated:
When the "Record and Run Settings" are set to open a specific url, I could get the scripts for log in the system, while after that, no script will be recorded, although I could still get the web element by "Object Spy".

I could be able to implement a working script just using Object Spy, but I really want to know the reason why "Record" does not work as expected.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues. Make sure you have the following patches installed in this order:

1. QTPWEB_00090
2. QTPSAP_00012
3. QTPSAP_00037
4. QTPSAP_00044

Also, when using ICWeb/CRM, make sure you append the suffix to your URL: "?sap-testmode=X")